SQL Server 2008R2 - data file grows back after shrinking and available to shrink again
After shrinking of datafile there is around 180Gb of free space on hard drive (prior to operation shrink file dialog also shows that it is possible to free up around 180Gb of space). After 1-2 days the datafile grows back to its original size (before shrink operation) and it is possible to shrink it again (Shrink file dialog shows again that it is possible to free up around 180Gb of space).
I strictly forced to maintain some free space on hard drive, so avoiding the shrink operation is not an option.
Looking for advice what could cause this issue and possible solution.

What are the growth settings on the database files?  There may be activities that are occurring on the database that create a lot of data (which would cause the file to grow), but then delete the data again (which is why it would be able to be shrunk again).  What is the purpose of the database?  (ie. what apps/systems is it the database for?).  Are there things running like overnight data imports (that might "stage" a lot of data during importing, but then clear that "staged" data after the import has completed).  Or what other regular processes are running against the database?

In essence, there could be LOTS of different reasons why this is occurring .....

most likely
You:

Have file growth set to a percentage
Are rebuilding indexes nightly

If you stop doing useless index maintenance and stick to just updating statistics, you'll likely solve the problem, but you should also change your database to grow by a predictable number.
When set to a percentage, the growths get out of control quickly. For example, 10% of a 1GB database is a lot different than 10% of a 100GB database.
